# What permission is required for a service account to deploy to Google App Engine using gcloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I have created a service account in order to deploy a project to google app engine.

The service account I have created has these two roles:

1. *App Engine -> App Engine Deployer*
2. *Storage -> Storage Object Admin*

I downloaded the json key file, and then run these commands:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json
gcloud -q app deploy app_deploy.yaml --version 1.0 --promote
```

I got this error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [403] Operation not allowed

Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "description": "The \"appengine.applications.get\" permission is required.",
      "resourceType": "gae.api"
    }
  ]
]
```

What role did I miss to add?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works if I replace the role `App Engine -> App Engine Deployer` with `App Engine -> App Engine Admin`.

No idea why `Deployer` will not be sufficient for app deployment.

Comment: Also might be relevant: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-bitbucket-app-engine

Comment: I'm not having any luck `App Engine Admin` even, `Project Owner` works but anything less and nothing.

Comment: To date, the following combo did the trick for me: `App Engine Deployer`, `App Engine Service Admin` and `Cloud Build Service Account`. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you should turn it into an answer :-)

Comment: Christophe Deliens is right and the permission he mentioned is the least privilege. If you use app engine admin only it can deploy if you use, gcloud -q app deploy app.yaml --no-promote (with no-promote flag). But if you need to promote to default or any other service you need that permission.

Answer (score 13):

As of January 2020, the [documentation for App Engine Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles?hl=en#app-engine-roles) states:

> Note: The App Engine Deployer (roles/appengine.deployer) role alone grants adequate permission to deploy using the App Engine Admin API. To use other App Engine tooling, like gcloud commands, you must also have the Compute Storage Admin (roles/compute.storageAdmin) and Cloud Build Editor (cloudbuild.builds.editor) roles.

However, this is not completely true:

1. The `cloudbuild.builds.editor` is **not sufficient** (I suspect an error in the doc here). Indeed, the CLI apparently needs the `storage.objects.list` permission which is provided by [`cloudbuild.builds.builder`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles?hl=en#cloud-build-roles).
2. After deployment, you'll get an error because you don't have permission to change traffic splits. Thus, you need `roles/appengine.serviceAdmin`.

So, here is the roles list that worked for me:

- `roles/appengine.deployer`
- `roles/appengine.serviceAdmin`
- `roles/compute.storageAdmin`
- `roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder`

Comment: This works, except I had to do Cloud Build Service Account instead of Cloud Build Builds Builder. Also, the storage admin role only needs to be added to the staging bucket and doesn't need to be for the whole project.

Comment: Note that the docs are updated: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/roles#recommended_role_for_application_deployment.  They specify `roles/appengine.deployer`, `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` as a bare minimum. FWIW I also needed to add serviceAdmin so that my pipeline could update traffic splits etc. However it's possible that it could be done with a less powerful role.

Answer (score 3):

These roles worked for me.  I'm using `gcloud` to deploy from AppVeyor.

- App Engine Deployer
- App Engine Service Admin
- Cloud Build Service Account
- Service Account User

Reference: https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud/issues/191#issuecomment-706039046

Answer (score 1):

I'm still parsing all of the various docs about this myself, but I stumbled upon [this list of predefined GAE roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles?hl=en_US&_ga=1.175529259.887486364.1495052785#predefined_roles), complete with the definition of the permissions they had. "Deployer" seems like kind of a misnomer...they maybe should have called it "NewDeployer" or something like that. Hope this helps!

EDIT - here's also the [App Engine-specific list of roles](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/access-control).

Cheers!
inger

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to grant Admin role for Storage.

You should only need grant following roles for service account:

- `App Engine Deployer`
- `Storage Object Creator` for only bucket `staging.<project-id>.appspot.com`
- `Storage Object Viewer` for only bucket `staging.<project-id>.appspot.com`

You may got some error because service account do not have permission to change traffic to new version (you have just deployed).
But deploy was successful & you can migrate to new version from console.

Following is message from my case.

> [INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Your deployment has
>   succeeded, but promoting the new version to default failed. You may
>   not have permissions to change traffic splits. Changing traffic splits
>   requires the Owner, Editor, App Engine Admin, or App Engine Service
>   Admin role. Please contact your project owner and use the `gcloud app
>   services set-traffic --splits <version>=1` command to redirect traffic
>   to your newly deployed version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **App Engine Deployer** or **App Engine Admin**

Depends on your needs.

In addition, according to the GCP  App Engine doc, you need to add three more rolls; https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/roles

> To deploy new versions, you must also have the Service Account User
> (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser) role on the assigned App Engine service
> account, and the Cloud Build Editor (roles/cloudbuild.builds.editor),
> and Cloud Storage Object Admin (roles/storage.objectAdmin) roles on
> the project.

```
 roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
 roles/cloudbuild.builds.editor
 roles/storage.objectAdmin
```